# Xamarin.Forms how to change default blue color on ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm creating mobile app in Xamarin.Forms. I have a problem with ios implementation, I need change default blue color in all button texts, switch etc. to my own color.

In Android I managed this by changing styles.xml and colors.xml but on iOS I have no idea how to change this.

Anyone know what and where I have to change?

Comment: UIKit Appearance API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/introduction-to-the-appearance-api

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/introduction-to-the-appearance-api):

> iOS lets you apply visual property settings at a static class level
> rather than on individual objects so that the change applies to all
> instances of that control in the application.

This functionality is exposed in Xamarin.iOS via a static `Appearance` property on all UIKit controls that support it.

So you can set the default appearance values in the first screen:

```
// Set the default appearance values
UIButton.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.LightGray;
UIButton.Appearance.SetTitleColor(UIColor.FromRGB(0,127,14), UIControlState.Normal);

UISlider.Appearance.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Red;
UISlider.Appearance.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
UISlider.Appearance.MaximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;

UIProgressView.Appearance.ProgressTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
UIProgressView.Appearance.TrackTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
```

You can also customize the color by :

```
UIButton button = new UIButton();
button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Red, UIControlState.Normal);
```